# This query would be too heavy , need to be refactored. how can i do?

Tags: sql, sql-server

This query would be too heavy, needs to be refactored. How can I do that?

Please help

```
SELECT 
    contract_type, SUM(fte), ROUND(SUM(fte * 100 / t.s ), 0) AS "% of total"
FROM 
    design_studio_testing.empfinal_tableau 
CROSS JOIN 
    (SELECT SUM(fte) AS s 
     FROM design_studio_testing.empfinal_tableau) t
GROUP BY 
    contract_type;
```

Output should be like this:

[image]

Comment: what do you mean by "heavy"? you can use a windowed aggregate to shorten the syntax but it might not improve perf at all

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use window functions:

```
SELECT contract_type,
       SUM(fte),
       ROUND(SUM(fte) * 100.0 / SUM(SUM(fte)) OVER (), 0) AS "% of total"
FROM design_studio_testing.empfinal_tableau 
GROUP BY contract_type;
```

That said, your original version should not be that much slower than this, unless perhaps `empfinal_tableau` is a view.

If it is a table, you could further speed this with an index on `empfinal_tableau(contract_type, fte)`.

Answer (score 0):

There is no need to sum over the expression:

```
fte * 100 / t.s
```

which may slow the process.

Get `SUM(fte)` and then multiply and divide:

```
SELECT g.contract_type, g.sum_fte,
  ROUND(100.0 * g.sum_fte / t.s, 0) AS [% of total]
FROM (
  SELECT 
    contract_type, 
    SUM(fte) AS sum_fte
  FROM design_studio_testing.empfinal_tableau 
  GROUP BY contract_type
) AS g CROSS JOIN (SELECT SUM(fte) AS s FROM design_studio_testing.empfinal_tableau) t
```

Edit for Oracle:

```
SELECT g.contract_type, g.sum_fte,
  ROUND(100.0 * g.sum_fte / t.s, 0) AS "% of total"
FROM (
  SELECT 
    contract_type, 
    SUM(fte) AS sum_fte
  FROM empfinal_tableau 
  GROUP BY contract_type
) g CROSS JOIN (SELECT SUM(fte) AS s FROM empfinal_tableau) t
```

Comment: this query not working for me sql developer not supported this brekets [% of total]

Comment: there is a typo, but not big deal: `ROUND(100.0 * g.sum_fte / t.s, 0) AS [% of total]`, and you could use double quotes if brackets give you trouble (as you have in your query/question): `....AS "% of total"`

Comment: @SurendraKumarSingh as lptr mentioned the square brackets is not the problem but there was a typo in round. Also are you sure that you are using SQL Server?

Comment: this query would be too heavy, needs to be refactored. as small query?

Comment: yes i have use AS "% of total" but in the cross join before g giving me error.

Comment: Are you sure you are not using Oracle?

Comment: Check this for SQL Server: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=13259225487869f09aae407a29622be5 the syntax is correct.

Comment: If you are using Oracle then check this code: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=546ed14fdde25ea91c7dce1752d697aa